# Python library for downloading L8-9 data from USGS EarthExplorer

Tags: python, software-recommendations, landsat, usgs, earth-explorer

A couple of years ago I used to work with Landsat-8 data. I was using [kapadia/usgs](https://github.com/kapadia/usgs) or [yannforget/landsatxplore](https://github.com/yannforget/landsatxplore) librairies to download data programmatically from USGS EarthExplorer.

Now I need to download this data again, but it seems these libraries are not maintained anymore.

Is there any up-to-date, currently maintained python library for searching and download Landsat-8 and -9 data from USGS EarthExplorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I recommend the [EODAG](https://github.com/CS-SI/eodag) library.

This library allows to search, aggregate results, and download data not only from USGS, but also from many other data providers, with a unified API regardless of the provider.